# How to add Nginx reverse proxy to existing image

Tags: docker, nginx

How would I add an nginx reverse proxy to an existing image?

For example I use https://github.com/Koenkk/zigbee2mqtt and this exposes a front end that only works over http.

I want to use the image but have the front end accessible only over https.   Adding a Nginx reverse proxy is quite simple but what is the best method?

Do I fork the repository and add Nginx and config into the build or do I create a new image based on the existing one?

Presumably if I create a new image based on the existing one the entrypoint is essentially lost so any setup done in that script would need to be replicated in my image?

**Edit:** I need to run this container on a macvlan network but I do not want the insecure http access available to other devices on that network.

Comment: You'd almost always run this in a separate container.  You may be able to get away with using the unmodified `nginx` image and mounting a config file into it.

Comment: But by adding it into a separate container that means the original container still needs to have the insecure port exposed so that proxy can access it.

Comment: You wouldn't have to publish the port outside the isolated Docker network space.

Comment: I will update the question later on but I am currently stuck with my home automation containers running on a macvlan network along with some other IoT devices.  I am running docker on an Unraid server and this is currently the only way I can get the containers to run on a specified vlan (until I get a second NIC)

Comment: Create docker-compose with two images, one is the ZigBee and another is your Nginx that forward all requests. Why you want the SSL over the ZigBee?

Comment: @Max SSL is for the front end not Zigbee itself.   This network has IoT devices on and I don't want them having uncontrolled access to list / control all zigbee devices and config as well as details of other servers (eg. the MQTT one).

I understand compose will create a default network for each project but how does this work in practice?   Is the end result any different to creating a docker network (and custom bridge) and then running the two images on this bridge?

Answer (score 0):

In this particular image there was an entrypoint and the best way I have found of doing this to override the entrypoint when running it.

The original entrypoint was `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh` and there was a CMD of `npm start`

After some hacking around (As I still cannot quite get my head around the combination of entry point and CMD) I created the following script which installs nginx if it insn't already installed as well as running the original entrypoint and CMD

The script and the config is on a volume so this persists across different instances of the image.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello"
. /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

if [[ `apk -e info nginx | wc -l ` -eq 0 ]]
then
  apk add nginx
  cd /etc/nginx/conf.d
  mv default.conf default.conf.disabled
  ln -s /app/data/nginx.conf nginx.conf
  mkdir /run/nginx
  echo "Installed Nginx"
fi

echo "Starting Nginx"
nginx &

npm init -y

echo "Starting Node"
npm start
```

Not sure if this is advisable or the best way of doing this but it seems to work reasonably well.